# Background images load but only two of them are displayed

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to place icons for my nav bar however only first two are displayed others don't. The icons are loaded in browser (checked in console).

Using materialize for styling.

```
ico.icon-s{
    height: 2em;
    width: 2.5em;
    top: .360em;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-self: center;
}
.i-home{
    background: url(icons/house.svg) no-repeat;
}
.i-faq{
    background: url(icons/question.svg) no-repeat;
}
.i-gallery{
    background: url(icons/painting.svg) no-repeat;
}
.i-event{
    background: url(icons/event.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

```
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
 <li><a href="#"><ico class="icon-s i-home"></ico>EESLEHT</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><ico class="icon-s i-faq"></ico>FAQ</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><ico class="icon-s i-gallery"></ico>GALERII</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><ico class="icon-s i-event"></ico>ÜRITUSED</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><ico class="icon-s i-birthday"></ico>SÜNNIPÄEV</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><ico class="icon-s i-booking"></ico>BRONEERIDA</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are the text in the links displayed?

Comment: Can you add a js-fiddle or code snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9f3p7dzb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your icons are quite large on some of the assets.

Add the following line to your css:

```
ico.icon-s{
    height: 2em;
    width: 2.5em;
    top: .360em;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-self: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bzaqr5g/)

Answer (score 0):

The SVGs that aren't visible have a width and height settings that forces them to render to a huge 512px. They're actually visible but all you see is their transparent background of the top left corner. Edit them to remove the `height` and `width` attributes so they are freely resizable (see the first two SVGs to compare).